# Find the total possible orderings of a finite set satisfying a partial ordering

Tags: order-theory

Consider a set of $n$ points $x_1, \dots, x_n$ such that none are equal i.e. $x_i = x_j \Rightarrow i = j$.

Now consider a partial ordering (this may not be the correct term to use in this case) represented by a set $S$ e.g.

$$ S = \{x_1 < x_2, x_2 < x_3 \} $$

My question is, how can we find the total number of actual orderings of our points that satisfy the partial ordering represented by $S$?

For example in the 3D case the ordering given by the above $S$ uniquely defines the actual order of the points $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$. However if instead

$$ S = \{x_1 < x_2, x_1 < x_3 \}, $$

there are now 2 possible actual orderings, $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ and $x_1 < x_3 < x_2$.

I noticed that these partial orderings can be represented by directed acyclic graphs. I then thought that there would be a fairly simple combinatorial approach to counting the total orderings possible satisfying one of these DAGs (in a sense, the DAG constrains the set of all possible orderings). However I kept running into special cases where any algorithm I came up with would break down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem of counting [linear extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension).

The short answer is that there's no polynomial-time algorithm unless P=NP, and in fact under a weaker assumption. A recent paper studying this problem is https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2017/74 - it has a good introduction and references.

Comment: Not only did this answer my question, but that paper is exactly the sort of further thing I was looking for.